# Team Foundation Server - set default repository for team

Tags: git, tfs

In TFS 2017, we have a big project with multiple teams and areas within it, as suggested in [this blog post](http://geekswithblogs.net/Optikal/archive/2013/09/05/153944.aspx).

I couldn't find out how to set a default Git repository for each of these teams, so the "Code" menu item at the top would point to a specific repository for each team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, we cannot achieve that. You have to navigate manually if you want to switch repository from one to another. It will not auto-switch, no such relationship between team and repository in TFS/VSTS.

As a workaround you can [add the repositories reflect each team to **Favorites**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/connect/account-home-pages#favorites-open-items-youve-marked-as-favorites), then you can switch to the corresponding repository conveniently from **My Favorites** in the account hub.

[image]